# Keyboard layout in lightdm greeter is not consistent

Tags: keyboard, lightdm, keyboard-layout, login-screen

I'm having a very frustrating keyboard configuration issue.  I have read all the references I can find for X11/xkb and lightdm, but I still can't figure this out.

We have a computer that is shared by several users who use different keyboard layout variants.  After one person logs out, the lightdm greeter seems to retain the variant from the last user.  How do I ensure that the user's preferred keyboard is also used for his/her login prompt?  If this is not possible, at the very least I would like to ensure that the basic US QWERTY keyboard is used for the login prompt.

I have a feeling the root issue is that I don't understand the hierarchy of the various places that keyboard layouts are read from.  I am used to my own system where everything is just in `/etc/defaults/keyboard`.  Once I am logged in, I can control my user settings just fine, but they login prompt is killing me.  Sometimes "En1" means the basic QWERTY keyboard, and sometimes "En1" is the `us:intl` keyboard with dead keys for diacritics.  I have to switch to "En2" to get the basic keyboard.